# Retrofit Closing Response Body

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I've been getting this error:

```
 A connection to ****** was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?
```

So I went on and close the responses I get.

```
response.body().close()
```

Problem is if the response.body() is already converted to a custom class, there's no close method available. Also I tried calling raw and gives me an exception:

```
fetchSomething.enqueue(new Callback<SomethingClass>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SomethingClass> call, Response<SomethingClass> response) {


                //Closes the response body
                response.raw().body().close(); //<--- gives illegalStateException

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SomethingClass> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }
```

How do I close it?

Comment: What is the `retrofit` and `okhttp`  version?

Comment: compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.0.0-beta4'

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.0.1"

Comment: Can you update `retrofit` and `okhttp` library and check the code again.

Comment: Those are very old versions. Update and try again. Retrofit 2 closes the ResponseBody for you; no need to do that at the application layer.

Comment: This did the trick, thank you @EricCochran

Comment: Also, @Soham, thank you

Comment: @EricCochran Does it also close the response.errorBody() automatically or we have to close it manually?

Comment: @Nick Closes the error body's source for you.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2311) you can do something like below

```
 ResponseBody body =  response.raw().body();
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    return body.string(); // Closes automatically.
                } else {
                    body.close();
                    return null;
                }
```

or

```
ResponseBody body = response.raw().body();
try {
  ...
} finally {
 body.close();
}
```

Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: This returns:

371-11371/com.billbii.billbiiapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.billbii.billbiiapplication, PID: 11371
                                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read raw response body of a converted body.

Comment: @KimMontano Did you got any solution?