# Retrofit Response body close

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I used retrofit just like on below code. But i can't find any solution and offical docs which help me to stop leaks and close response body. Maybe somebody know how it should looks like?
My Retrofit call:

```
PlacesAPI.Factory.getInstance().getPlaces().enqueue(new Callback<Places>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Places> call, Response<Places> response) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getPosts().size(); i++) {
                        if (response.body().getPosts().get(i).getNazwa().equals(shopName)) {
                            addMarker(Double.parseDouble(response.body().getPosts().get(i).getDlug()),
                                    Double.parseDouble(response.body().getPosts().get(i).getSzer()));
                        }
                    }
                                    }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Places> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: You cannot call `response.body()` more than once

Comment: after add all marker on map i try to clear response. I read in offical docs that always close() should be done. Also android studio throw me info on logcat that i have leaks and not used close() where it can be use. After that i check heap by Eclipse Mat and i see many response objects.

Comment: There should be only one response object since it's the one parameter

Comment: are you using retrofit 2?

Comment: yes, retrofit 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor your code.

Its not efficient to grab the response body repeatedly

In order words, see link below

> The response body can be consumed only once

```
final List<Post> posts = response.body().getPosts();
for (Post p : posts) {
    if (p.getNazwa().equals(shopName)) {
        addMarker(Double.parseDouble(p.getDlug()), Double.parseDouble(p.getSzer()));
}
```

And, according to the documentation, yes, the response must be closed, so use a `try` block to accomplish that

https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html

Comment: and how to use close statment in your solution?

Comment: maybe it not making any leaks and onDestroy on this activity clean everything by GC?

Comment: You're welcome to use `try-finally ` block. The `close` method exists in the documentation, if you would like to find it

Comment: cricket_007 ...+1 for your name

Answer (score 0):

This might help;

```
response.raw().body().close();
```

According to this,  retrofit 2 closes the body for you

[Retrofit Closing Response Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39482514/retrofit-closing-response-body) .

Comment: I'm seeing a "Explicit termination method 'close' not called" with the latest version of all dependencies, I suppose it's because of the cache and File used to init it, but not sure where to close this or if it should be manually closed at all, cannot find any code samples yet.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try to not use anonymous class there as callback?
Try to create a class member instead.

```
private Callback<Places> mCallback = new Callback<Places>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Places> call, Response<Places> response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getPosts().size(); i++) {
                    if (response.body().getPosts().get(i).getNazwa().equals(shopName)) {
                        addMarker(Double.parseDouble(response.body().getPosts().get(i).getDlug()),
                                Double.parseDouble(response.body().getPosts().get(i).getSzer()));
                    }
                }
                                }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Places> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
PlacesAPI.Factory.getInstance().getPlaces().enqueue(mCallback);
```

Please try and let a comment to inform all of us :).

Comment: and if i use your solution i should not to close reponse?

Comment: Sorry, my bad.Try with this. https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2311

Comment: How does the member variable act any different than anonymous class?