# How to solve memory leaks problem in android retrofit?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, retrofit2, okhttp

I faced this problem in one of my existing android apps

```
  A connection to myapicall was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?
```

I have used those versions of `retrofit` and `OkHttp` in my existing android app and I found in logcat that there are lots of memory leaks as it says 'do you forget to close OkHttp as it has got memory leaks..'

```
// ok http
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
 //for body in retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
  // for retro fit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    // if you are using proguard follow this link
    //http://square.github.io/retrofit/
    // for rxjava
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
```

I found some of the [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39482514/retrofit-closing-response-body) suggest that upgraded version of okhttp and retrofit will handle the memory leaks automatically and some [posts](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2311) suggest that I need to use `try{}finally{ response.body().close();}` but as I have response in generic type `<T>` so I wont be able to access `.close()` method at all. Since I was able to use to access `body().rawResponse().close()` :

```
 public void refreshRemoteAcademicCalendar(int skip, int top, String type) {
        Call<AcademicCalendarModel.AcademicCalendarMetaData> request = academicCalendarService.getEventsAcademicCalendar(skip, top, "Type eq '" + type + "'");

        academicCalendarService.getEventsAcademicCalendar(skip, top, "Type eq '" + type + "'").enqueue(new Callback<AcademicCalendarModel.AcademicCalendarMetaData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AcademicCalendarModel.AcademicCalendarMetaData> call, Response<AcademicCalendarModel.AcademicCalendarMetaData> response) {

                try {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        List<AcademicCalendarModel> results = response.body().getValue();
                        for (AcademicCalendarModel academicCalendar : results) {
                            saveDataToDatabase(academicCalendar);
                        }

                    }
                }finally {
                    response.raw().body().close();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AcademicCalendarModel.AcademicCalendarMetaData> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

which then leads to another problem:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read the raw response body of a converted body.
                      at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$NoContentResponseBody.source(OkHttpCall.java:267)
                      at okhttp3.ResponseBody.close(ResponseBody.java:187)
```

Comment: can you please also tell how you initialize `academicCalendarService`

Comment: academicCalendarService = RetrofitClient.getRetrofitClient(application).create(AcademicCalendarService.class); // create instance of retrofitClient

Comment: you can use `ResponseBody` from `okhttp3` in the response type instead. But in that case you will need to convert the json to POJO manually. Please also note that response.body() is a stream, so you can only read the value once.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Okttp is leaking and i could do nothing about it.

Comment: @IPKaal have you found any solution ? Facing similar problem and trying to fix it

Comment: Nope I have left it as it is at the moment needs more free time as I am on tight schedule atm. If anything I will let you know. Thank you